# What is a super method in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In *Javascript: The Good Parts*, Crockford gives the following example:

```
Object.method('superior', function(name) {
    var that = this,
    method = that[name];
    return function() {
        return method.apply(that, arguments);
    };
});
```

What is going on here?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that `Object.method` is a shortcut for modifying an object's `prototype`.

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
   this.prototype[name] = func;
return this;
};
```

Comment: Crockford is doing weird stuff without explaining :-) How much context do you have, do you know how that method is (supposed to be) called and what `Object.method` does?